# Can I reference an external database as the properties of a model in viewer?

Tags: database, asp.net-web-api, external, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-data-management

I'm attempting to create an instance of the Forge-viewer API to reference an outside database (Homemade, not bim360 or Fusion) as the Properties of an object selected. (i.e. the database parameters fill-in the properties window) However, I'm unable to find a method. What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start would be the below code samples:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/adding-custom-properties-property-panel
- https://github.com/yiskang/forge-au-sample/tree/master/properties
- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs //interaction with custom data source and many data centric plugins

Basically you will need to customize the model property panel and feed in your own data source by extending `Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerPropertyPanel` and `setProperties/setNodeProperties` ...

Comment: Thank you for these links! Unfortunately i'm not able to get the first link to work correctly after following the steps. The ForgeViewer.js has a different line to replace than the last step is asking me to replace it with and I think that might be the issue?

Comment: If you are on v7 then the Viewer Application has been deprecated - see [here](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/skeleton) to register and load extensions

Comment: Now that I am able to fill in my own data, how can i script or reference an outside data table? (i.e. Excel Spreadsheet)

Comment: You can load spreadsheets directly in the browser using [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) - there are quite a few options if you look them up on Google/Github etc